# random chars in dynamic char array C

Tags: c, arrays, random, chars

I need help with char array. I want to create a n-lenght array and initialize its values, but after malloc() function the array is longer then n*sizeof(char), and the content of array isnt only chars which I assign... In array is few random chars and I dont know how to solve that... I need that part of code for one project for exam in school, and I have to finish by Sunday... Please help :P

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){

    char *text;

    int n = 10;

    int i;

    if((text = (char*) malloc((n)*sizeof(char))) == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr, "allocation error");
    }

    for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
        //text[i] = 'A';
        strcat(text,"A");
    }

    int test = strlen(text);
    printf("\n%d\n", test);

    puts(text);
    free(text);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can only store 9 characters in text, because you have to reserve one character for null termination. And [don't cast the result of `malloc` in C](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start with, you're way of using `malloc` in

```
text = (char*) malloc((n)*sizeof(char)
```

is not ideal. You can change that to

```
text = malloc(n * sizeof *text); // Don't cast and using *text is straighforward and easy.
```

So the statement could be

```
if(NULL == (text = (char*) malloc((n)*sizeof(char))){
    fprintf(stderr, "allocation error");
}
```

But the actual problem lies in

```
for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
    //text[i] = 'A';
    strcat(text,"A");
}
```

The `strcat` documentation says

> dest − This is pointer to the destination array, which should contain
>   a C string, and should be large enough to contain the concatenated
>   resulting string.

Just to point out that the above method is flawed, you just need to consider that the C string `"A"` actually contains two characters in it, <kbd>A</kbd> and the terminating <kbd>\0</kbd>(the null character). In this case, when `i` is `n-2`, you have out of bounds access or buffer overrun<sup>`1`</sup>. If you wanted to fill the entire `text` array with <kbd>A</kbd>, you could have done

```
for(i = 0; i < n; i++){ 
    // Note for n length, you can store n-1 chars plus terminating null
    text[i]=(n-2)==i?'A':'\0'; // n-2 because, the count starts from zero
}
//Then print the null terminated string
printf("Filled string : %s\n",text); // You're all good :-)
```

---

<sup>**Note**: Use a tool like  [**valgrind**](http://valgrind.org/)  to find memory leaks & out of bound memory accesses.</sup>

Answer (score 3):

Well before using `strcat` make

```
text[0]=0;
```

`strcat` expects null terminated `char` array for the first argument also.

From [standard 7.24.3.1](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.24.3.1)

```
  #include <string.h>
          char *strcat(char * restrict s1,
               const char * restrict s2);
```

> The strcat function appends a copy of the string pointed to by s2
>   (including the terminating null character) to the end of the string
>   pointed to by s1. The initial character of s2 overwrites the null
>   character at the end of s1.

How do you think `strcat` will know where the first string ends if you don't
put a `\0` in `s1`.

Also don't forget to allocate an extra byte for the `\0` character. Otherwise you are writing past what you have allocated for. This is again undefined behavior.

And earlier you had undefined behavior.

Note:

- You should check the return value of `malloc` to know whether the `malloc` invocation was successful or not.
- Casting the return value of `malloc` is not needed. Conversion from `void*` to relevant pointer is done implicitly in this case.
- `strlen` returns `size_t` not `int`. `printf("%zu",strlen(text))`